# Can anyone explain these two inconsistent results? Partial derivative calculation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

Let $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$. Find $r_x$.

My answer: $r_x=(r_x)^{-1}=x_r=(\cos \theta)^{-1}$.

Book answer: $$\frac{\partial (r^2)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (x^2+y^2)}{\partial x} \implies 2rr_x=2x \implies r_x =\frac{x}{r}=\cos \theta$$

I suspect my answer is incorrect but I don't see why that is the case can anyone offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where this condition "$r_x$ equals $(r_x)^{-1}$" is coming from?

Comment: $$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}}$$ right?

Comment: Like in some cases when you want to find $$\frac{dy}{dx}$$ instead you find $$\frac{dx}{dy}$$ and invert?